# Ubuntu 20.04 wifi disconnects and then reconnects after every few minutes (sometimes even seconds)

Tags: networking, wireless, 20.04, hot-spot

I have tried many solutions but nothing seems to be working. Only wired connection works consistently. On my same laptop, I have Windows 10 installed as well and I never get this problem at all. So, clearly this is an ubuntu issue.

Also, I don't know how relevant this is, but it started happening after I started using my mobile phone's hotspot instead of wifi (whenever I am outside). I don't seem to encounter this problem when the laptop is connected to my phone's hotspot. However, now it can't keep a consistent connection with wifi. Also, sometimes, the wifi pyramid icon on the top right turns completely green. Is that normal?

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos and provide wireless script results

Comment: Here I have pasted the results: https://newtextdocument.com/6828d10dba

Comment: So, I don't have this issue when I am connected to my phone's hotspot.